# How do you write a sql statement that creates a new column for a date value and then queries it in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, date, subquery, dateadd

I have written a sql statement as so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
   SELECT DATEADD(dd, 60, PaymentDate) AS NewPaymentDate, * 
   FROM MyTable
) x 
WHERE x.NewPaymentDate >=" & Date() & " 
  AND Archived=0
```

But it is returning

> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

PaymentDate is a Date format in the database - but do i have to format the new date column 'NewPaymentDate' into a date format and if so, how do i do this?

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Which language/environment are you using SQL in?

Comment: You are comparing a DATE `x.NewPaymentDate` against a VARCHAR `& Date() &`. That may be the issue.

Comment: It looks a lot like SQL Server or Sybase.

Comment: What is `" & Date() & "` supposed to be?

Comment: yes it is sql server - the Date()  is ASP but i can use database date as suggested in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like SQL Server syntax.  Why do you need to pass in the current date?  Just use the database date:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM (SELECT DATEADD(day, 60, PaymentDate) AS NewPaymentDate, t.* 
      FROM MyTable t
     ) t
WHERE t.NewPaymentDate >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND
      t.Archived = 0;
```

If you want to pass a value in, learn to use *parameters* to pass values in -- the syntax varies depending on the API you are using for accessing the database.

Comment: Thankyou - this has worked a treat. There is just one issue now in that the code takes a long time to run and times out (there are 11,000 records!). But maybe that is another question!